# How to merge upstream changes into my own GitHub fork?

Tags: github, fork

am under the impression that to keep my fork of an open source project update-to-date, i must find some way to merge any upstream changes into my GitHub fork of that project, THEN clone them down onto my local syatem to do the next branch, etc.

Can anyone pls tell me how to keep my GitHub fork in-synch with the upstream project? The info. i find just leaves me baffled as how to do that.
Thanx

Comment: Let me try this again: there is an upstream open source github project that i have forked into my own G/H repo. cloned from mine into my own pc, made mods, pushed back2 my repo, did PULL req. for upstream. That was accepted. Now other mods to upstream means my GH fork is behind. Must i take some action to bring U/S mods into my GH fork so i can clone to local again?

Answer (score 0):

Use `git pull` if you did `git clone`. It is worthwhile working through the guide https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git/ and basic intro: http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Getting-Started.